# How can I move a nested class to a separate file

Tags: python, class

In my Python class I have a nested class defined and it works well, but when I try to move the nested class to a separate file I'm having trouble importing it.

I've tried to follow a few tutorials on Mixins and importing but I keep running into the issue of my object not having the attribute of the new method.

```py
class SomeClass():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  # # This works
  # class NestedClass():
  #   def helloWorld():
  #     print("Hello World")

  # But when I move it to a separate file (nestedclass.py) I'm having trouble importing
  from nestedclass import NestedClass


c = SomeClass()
c.NestedClass.helloWorld() # throws an error when I try to import
```

The error message I receive is "Attribute Error: 'NestedClass' object has no attribute 'helloWorld'

Comment: so if I want to keep everything within `SomeClass` I need to keep it in a single file?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. There's some issue with `helloWorld` being an instance method with no parameters, but as you are accessing it as a class attribute, it works out.

Comment: If you want it to be a Nested class, why would you move it to a separate file? I mean, even if this worked, it will not be a nested class, just another class...

Comment: @Tomerikoo A nested class is really just a class-valued attribute; where the class actually gets defined doesn't matter as much.

Comment: @Jhsu There is a *huge* difference between a nested class and a mix-in.

Comment: I know this is why this seems weird. The import could be in the start of the file and then in the class do `nested = NestedClass()`